# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.SnowflakeResultSetPartition

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-connector

I am trying to use spark 3.0 to read data from snowflake.

My snowflake packages version are:

`"net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.8.4-spark_3.0," "net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.12.17"`

Any quick pointer what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: @xsqioan, Im facing same issue on glue. Were you able to resolve it. Thanks!